# Full text search in the Attached documents in Kentico CMS 7

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, kentico

Is there any way in which I can search the attachments and show the attached documents in the search result? My search result should show only the attachments in which the search text is contained. Right now I can search the attachments and the page in which the attachment contains search text is shown.
Say, I have a Page Home and attachment myattachment.docx as its attachment. While searching Background as search text in the Site search, which is contained only in the myattachment.docx (not contained in Home page) , the search result show Home page as a search result. What I am intending is to return something like Home/ myattachment.docx as a result instead of Home page. My page may any number of attachments.

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 0):

The info on this is a little bit sketch. See below for the documentation I used.

Create a custom global event handler in AppCode (or Old_App_Code), make sure it is a partial class of CMSModule Loader.

Add your custom event handler in the overriden `Init()` The one you want is `DocumentEvents.GetContent.Execute`.

The sender object should be the current `TreeNode` being indexed for search. You can then use that node to access the relevant attachments and modify the event args `e.content` to add your document text to the search.

```
[CustomDocumentEvents]
public partial class CMSModuleLoader
{
    private class CustomDocumentEventsAttribute : CMSLoaderAttribute
    {
        public override void Init()
        {
            // Assigns custom handlers to the appropriate events
            DocumentEvents.GetContent.Execute += Document_GetContent;
        }

        private void Document_GetContent(object sender, DocumentEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNode node = sender as TreeNode;
            if (node != null)
            {
                //Note, this is psuedo code, this isnt the way to iterate over TreeNode.Attachments
                foreach( attachment in node.Attachments ) {
                    e.Content += attachment.content;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

More info

See http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html?event_handlers_overview.htm for implementing custom events in general in version 7.

See this for custom search in version 5
http://devnet.kentico.com/Knowledge-Base/Search/How-to-search-for-documents-using-assigned-categor.aspx

See http://devnet.kentico.com/Knowledge-Base/API-and-Internals/Custom-Handler-Library-compatibility.aspx for the updated event name for version 7 referred to in the version 5 custom search example.